# How do I debug an incoming connection? (This is NOT a "How do I remote debug?" quest10n!)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging

I have a QA virtual machine running Windows 7 Professional with IE10 installed (VM) and I have my development machine running Windows 7 Professional, IIS 7.5 with Visual Studio 2012 Professional installed (DM).

On the VM, I've changed the host file to map to the IP address of a particular url on my DM which hosts a website using IIS 7.5. When the VM connects to my DM website using IE10, I want to debug that connection using VS 2012 on my DM. However, from my DM, when I attach to IIS using VS 2012 Professional, I never hit a breakpoint - it appears that the debug session on my DM knows nothing about the VM's current connection to my web site.

How can I set this up so I can debug the incoming VM connection using VS 2012 on 
my DM?

P.S. Uninstalling IE11, installing IE10 in order to debug on my DM, then reinstalling IE11 is not really an option, as my DM has been corrupted from doing that a number of times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong url on the VM. Works as advertised :)